# How to measure function run times

Tags: go, profiling

In a golang web server I want to measure times taken by some http controller. I am calling `time.Now()` before calling controller function, and `time.Since()` after controller function returns. But if it has long remote io request that takes 1 second, or the process is throttled, or controller is parallelized with goroutines - then that time will be not exactly what I want.

If we assume analogy to bash `time` command - then I am getting `real` time with this technique:

```
time go build

real    0m5,204s
user    0m12,012s
sys 0m2,043s
```

How can I measure `user` and `sys` times for a function run(preferably for a goroutine plus its forked children) in a golang program (preferably with standard packages)?

this is my profiler implementation. How can i extend it with sys and user time per goroutine?

```
const HeaderCost = "Cost"

// Timed middleware will set Cost header in http response
func Timed(h http.Handler) http.HandlerFunc {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        h.ServeHTTP(&responseWriterWithTimer{
            ResponseWriter: w,
            headerWritten:  false,
            startedAt:      time.Now(),
        }, r)
    })
}

type responseWriterWithTimer struct {
    http.ResponseWriter
    headerWritten bool
    startedAt     time.Time
}

func (w *responseWriterWithTimer) WriteHeader(statusCode int) {
    w.Header().Set(
        HeaderCost,
        strconv.FormatFloat(
            time.Since(w.startedAt).Seconds(),
            'g',
            64,
            64,
        ),
    )
    w.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader(statusCode)
    w.headerWritten = true
}

func (w *responseWriterWithTimer) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    if !w.headerWritten {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    }
    return w.ResponseWriter.Write(b)
}
```

Comment: You can measure CPU time at the process level using something like https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil It doesn't appear to me that doing this at Go routine-level is presently possible. Measuring real time should be fine if you measure precisely your handler and nothing else.

Comment: @Zyl process level includes all threads, where each thread runs unknown amount of goroutines. So it wont be a correct measure.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do basic instrumentation at runtime, you can wrap your handlers to measure their execution time:

```
func perfMiddleware(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        t := time.Now()
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        log.Printf("handler took %s", time.Since(t))
    })
}
```

You could expose this more easily using [`expvar`](https://pkg.go.dev/expvar). Going beyond this, there are also numerous instrumentation/telemetry/APM libraries available for Go if you look for them, along with metrics management solutions like the TICK stack, Datadog, and so on.

As for the `real`, `user`, and `sys` data output by `time`, these are posix measures that don't perfectly apply to instrumenting a Go HTTP handler (or any other unit of code at runtime), for a number of reasons:

- goroutines have no parent/child relationship; all are equal peers, so there is no metric of the time taken by "children" of your handler.
- most of the I/O is handled within the stdlib, which isn't instrumented to this level (and instrumentation at this level would have a non-negligible performance impact of its own)

You can of course instrument each piece individually, which is often more useful; for example, instrument your HTTP handlers, as well as any code that is making its own external requests, in order to measure the performance of each component. From this you can analyze the data and get a much clearer picture of what is taking time, in order to address any performance issues you find.

Comment: That would be a separate question, with different tags, to catch the attention of C developers rather than Go developers. Threading/concurrency work very differently in Go compared to C. I'm not sure what you mean by "golang programs and functions does not have cpu time".

Comment: There is a function. Function is ultimately in machine code. I want to measure how much cores*seconds (like man-hours) cpu spent actively executing that function assembly, being in user mode. If you will look at the program as a function - you may measure its execution time by prepending `time` to command in bash. I want that instrumentation more granular - for a golang controller function. `time.Since` does not work - it is also accouting cpu idle time - that is not a solution.

Comment: That's not what `time` does. `time` yields existing kernel metrics on CPU use at the *process* level. No such metrics exist at the thread level, and certainly not at the goroutine level (which is not even a concept that exists in the kernel). If you look at the program as a function, and then try to invert the logic to make assumptions about a function based on what's true of a program, you're going to wind up with some baseless and inaccurate assumptions about how these things work.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to measure something in isolation, [benchmarks](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#hdr-Benchmarks) are probably exactly what you're after.

If you're trying to measure a `http.Handler`, you can use [`httptest.NewRecorder`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httptest#NewRecorder) and [`httptest.NewRequest`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httptest#NewRequest) to create a new response writer and request object and just invoke the handler directly inside your benchmark.

```
func BenchmnarkHttpHandler(b*testing.B) {

  req := httptest.NewRequest("GET", "/foo", nil)

  myHandler := thingtotest.Handler{}

  for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
     myHandler.ServeHTTP(httptest.NewRecorder(), req);
  }
}
```

Comment: No, I want to measure request not in isolation but in a producion system. And main thing is that I want not measure real time, but a user/sys time of a serving goroutine and its forked children. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I measure user and sys times for a function run

You cannot. That distinction is not an observable for Go functions.

(But honestly: Measuring them is of no real use and doesn't make much sense. This sound like a XY problem.)

Comment: I need something like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65150085/1976993
But not even with RUSAGE_THREAD, but with RUSAGE_GOROUTINE

Comment: go scheduler may measure cycles when it puts goroutine to sleep. each controller function run is a goroutine. so its implementable. why makes no sense?.. dont get you

Comment: @xakepp35 "go scheduler may measure cycles" it may, but actually it doesn't. I still do not get what you want to do with that metric. Which action would you derive from that data that you cannot from "normal" profiling (profile, block, mutex, trace etc). Btw: Your "I want this because I said I want it" attitude might seem a bit rude to others.

Comment: @xakepp35 Thanks for clarifying. The answer is "No you cannot." Enough said.